# Dependency issue with support-library-v4

Tags: android, eclipse

I would like to import 2 existing projects as libraries in Eclipse.
Both library projects depends on the `support-library-v4` and have a .jar file.
So when I import them I am asked to fix the dependencies. I get this error:

```
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

How to fix that?

Comment: can you build those two projects? what error are you getting?

Comment: I updated my question: Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: Probably those jars are of different versions. Copy the same jar two both libs and try again.

Comment: Hi, having the same jar for both was actually the right answer. Thanks.  Please update your answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Right click your Project Preferences of your Library.
2. Click Java Build Path
3. Remove the android-support-v4 jar you see in the "root"

Comment: I tried that one as well but thanks. I fixed this by removing the .jar from the projects and add the library as an external jar to both projects.

Comment: if my answer was helpful at all, please consider upping or accepting it.

Comment: NathanZ's comment was the fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common error that can occur if you are using the same library of different builds in two or more projects. The best way to solve this is to right click on all your projects and reinstall your android support library.

NB: Remember to use the library source files